# Reading google docs line by line in google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

Is it possible in google apps script to read text line by line on docs? I am trying to get a value for the "end space" at the end of a paragraph (the amount of distance from the last character of the paragraph to the right margin). This would be equivalent to getIndentLastLine() (in comparison to getIndentFirstLine() ) in the Google Paragraph Object, if it existed.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading text line by line in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531644/reading-text-line-by-line-in-google-apps-script)